# Getting date to appear on x axis of plot.stl method in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to get the dates to appear on the x axis of an stl plot.

```
 res<- (stl(ts(data[,variable],frequency=52,start=as.Date(data[1,date]) ),s.window="per",robust=TRUE) ) 
plot(res)
```

[image]

However this is just producing some unicode labels at the bottom of the chart, I have also tried chaning as.Date to as.character however this didn't work.

dput of some data:

```
structure(c("2007-01-01", "2007-01-08", "2007-01-15", "2007-01-22", 
"2007-01-29", "2007-02-05", "2007-02-12", "2007-02-19", "2007-02-26", 
"2007-03-05", "2007-03-12", "2007-03-19", "2007-03-26", "2007-04-02", 
"2007-04-09", "2007-04-16", "2007-04-23", "2007-04-30", "2007-05-07", 
"2007-05-14", "2007-05-21", "2007-05-28", "2007-06-04", "2007-06-11", 
"2007-06-18", "2007-06-25", "2007-07-02", "2007-07-09", "2007-07-16", 
"2007-07-23", "2007-07-30", "2007-08-06", "2007-08-13", "2007-08-20", 
"2007-08-27", "2007-09-03", "2007-09-10", "2007-09-17", "2007-09-24", 
"2007-10-01", "2007-10-08", "2007-10-15", "2007-10-22", "2007-10-29", 
"2007-11-05", "2007-11-12", "2007-11-19", "2007-11-26", "2007-12-03", 
"2007-12-10", "2007-12-17", "2007-12-24", "2007-12-31", "2008-01-07", 
"2008-01-14", "2008-01-21", "2008-01-28", "2008-02-04", "2008-02-11", 
"2008-02-18", "2008-02-25", "2008-03-03", "2008-03-10", "2008-03-17", 
"2008-03-24", "2008-03-31", "2008-04-07", "2008-04-14", "2008-04-21", 
"2008-04-28", "2008-05-05", "2008-05-12", "2008-05-19", "2008-05-26", 
"2008-06-02", "2008-06-09", "2008-06-16", "2008-06-23", "2008-06-30", 
"2008-07-07", "2008-07-14", "2008-07-21", "2008-07-28", "2008-08-04", 
"2008-08-11", "2008-08-18", "2008-08-25", "2008-09-01", "2008-09-08", 
"2008-09-15", "2008-09-22", "2008-09-29", "2008-10-06", "2008-10-13", 
"2008-10-20", "2008-10-27", "2008-11-03", "2008-11-10", "2008-11-17", 
"2008-11-24", "2008-12-01", "2008-12-08", "2008-12-15", "2008-12-22", 
"2008-12-29", "2009-01-05", "2009-01-12", "2009-01-19", "2009-01-26", 
"2009-02-02", "2009-02-09", "2009-02-16", "2009-02-23", "2009-03-02", 
"2009-03-09", "2009-03-16", "2009-03-23", "2009-03-30", "2009-04-06", 
"2009-04-13", "2009-04-20", "2009-04-27", "2009-05-04", "2009-05-11", 
"2009-05-18", "2009-05-25", "2009-06-01", "2009-06-08", "2009-06-15", 
"2009-06-22", "2009-06-29", "2009-07-06", "2009-07-13", "2009-07-20", 
"2009-07-27", "2009-08-03", "2009-08-10", "2009-08-17", "2009-08-24", 
"2009-08-31", "2009-09-07", "2009-09-14", "2009-09-21", "2009-09-28", 
"2009-10-05", "2009-10-12", "2009-10-19", "2009-10-26", "2009-11-02", 
"2009-11-09", "2009-11-16", "2009-11-23", "2009-11-30", "2009-12-07", 
"2009-12-14", "2009-12-21", "2009-12-28", "2010-01-04", "2010-01-11", 
"2010-01-18", "2010-01-25", "2010-02-01", "2010-02-08", "2010-02-15", 
"2010-02-22", "2010-03-01", "2010-03-08", "2010-03-15", "2010-03-22", 
"2010-03-29", "2010-04-05", "2010-04-12", "2010-04-19", "2010-04-26", 
"2010-05-03", "2010-05-10", "2010-05-17", "2010-05-24", "2010-05-31", 
"2010-06-07", "2010-06-14", "2010-06-21", "2010-06-28", "2010-07-05", 
"2010-07-12", "2010-07-19", "2010-07-26", "2010-08-02", "2010-08-09", 
"2010-08-16", "2010-08-23", "2010-08-30", "2010-09-06", "2010-09-13", 
"2010-09-20", "2010-09-27", "2010-10-04", "2010-10-11", "2010-10-18", 
"2010-10-25", "2010-11-01", "2010-11-08", "2010-11-15", "2010-11-22", 
"2010-11-29", "2010-12-06", "2010-12-13", "2010-12-20", "2010-12-27", 
"2011-01-03", "2011-01-10", "2011-01-17", "2011-01-24", "2011-01-31", 
"2011-02-07", "2011-02-14", "2011-02-21", "2011-02-28", "2011-03-07", 
"2011-03-14", "2011-03-21", "2011-03-28", "2011-04-04", "2011-04-11", 
"2011-04-18", "2011-04-25", "2011-05-02", "2011-05-09", "2011-05-16", 
"2011-05-23", "2011-05-30", "2011-06-06", "2011-06-13", "2011-06-20", 
"2011-06-27", "2011-07-04", "2011-07-11", "2011-07-18", "2011-07-25", 
"2011-08-01", "2011-08-08", "2011-08-15", "2011-08-22", "2011-08-29", 
"2011-09-05", "2011-09-12", "2011-09-19", "2011-09-26", "2011-10-03", 
"2011-10-10", "2011-10-17", "2011-10-24", "2011-10-31", "2011-11-07", 
"2011-11-14", "2011-11-21", "2011-11-28", "2011-12-05", "2011-12-12", 
"2011-12-19", "2011-12-26", "442573", "452832", "452785", "459228", 
"479509", "477631", "465619", "462001", "485567", "462381", "456059", 
"457401", "474094", "468766", "456945", "539126", "545640", "511801", 
"486619", "484430", "481428", "470622", "479677", "486755", "477617", 
"483656", "497479", "493436", "480080", "481527", "516029", "532349", 
"503939", "472171", "461550", "504532", "489715", "480032", "488376", 
"470772", "467395", "488155", "455712", "474456", "471237", "482943", 
"459320", "456956", "465056", "461930", "441201", "451255", "464508", 
"449199", "455411", "476323", "521761", "513416", "521070", "497596", 
"485461", "485593", "461148", "429938", "441207", "459484", "462099", 
"469285", "454395", "456729", "469251", "517727", "526719", "477985", 
"484538", "469766", "472399", "481162", "479039", "481071", "485068", 
"462108", "459079", "452410", "488574", "502166", "504323", "514529", 
"524206", "504315", "462935", "461899", "461551", "455491", "456857", 
"443314", "454586", "458943", "450555", "454311", "442808", "440126", 
"414876", "415787", "413352", "423864", "448319", "415440", "431948", 
"433313", "448509", "436400", "454154", "454183", "447735", "452220", 
"451433", "472808", "446767", "426595", "463693", "435673", "452704", 
"456828", "465069", "448685", "457353", "443859", "463972", "480139", 
"493342", "500982", "529602", "527365", "512005", "484585", "455007", 
"470006", "477522", "443956", "459038", "488877", "466669", "476242", 
"470862", "457298", "466438", "454062", "460216", "466645", "445113", 
"457255", "451553", "451504", "447991", "435100", "416140", "481390", 
"489041", "496984", "486245", "478191", "455201", "448085", "459097", 
"480859", "490248", "462523", "489755", "468391", "460229", "481276", 
"472845", "481099", "476435", "487314", "475043", "476847", "461928", 
"483488", "479379", "456732", "461538", "480773", "471101", "459898", 
"482129", "464356", "459420", "457850", "456764", "438152", "467928", 
"464732", "458767", "470256", "449488", "433263", "428548", "435099", 
"429163", "424251", "434723", "425841", "399498", "418791", "405051", 
"385037", "425144", "418296", "397644", "414283", "431907", "429117", 
"424862", "439664", "432791", "443588", "434985", "442418", "445760", 
"449290", "451412", "456247", "444372", "441390", "458192", "456435", 
"450670", "447609", "439083", "464513", "462784", "439423", "450857", 
"442374", "447753", "440207", "435254", "430841", "437233", "426523", 
"430127", "431305", "470244", "508878", "511064", "504182", "462076", 
"452218", "426535", "436892", "459008", "441449", "438783", "427497", 
"432275", "436745", "423068", "429574", "416074"), .Dim = c(261L, 
2L))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with how you have created the time series object. 
?ts will give you

> start : the time of the first observation. **Either a single number or a
>   vector of two integers**, which specify a natural time unit and a
>   (1-based) number of samples into the time unit.

Since your data starts at 2007-01-01 and is a weekly data, you have to specify c(2007,1), Note that the "1" here denotes that data start from the 1st week of 2007, as the data is weekly. Here the frequency should be set to 52 because, after 52 cycles/weeks a year will change from 2007 to 2008.

This should work

```
res<- (stl(ts(data[,2],frequency=52,start=c(2007,1 )),s.window="per",robust=TRUE) )
```

[image]